# Go to nth fragment of fragmentactivity using Button onclick

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 6 fragments of different category ,and Activity A.... Activity A have Dropdown List of           category which is specified 6 fragments.. My question is how to go to the 3rd fragment when i click 3rd position of category from dropdown ItemList...
Please Help......Thanks in advance ...

```
public class MissMaliniActivity extends FragmentActivity{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private PagerAdapter1 mPagerAdapter;
 private ViewPager mPager;
 List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.latest_list2);

      fragments.add((Fragment.instantiate(this,Home.class.getName())));
      fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Bollywood.class.getName()));
      fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fashion.class.getName()));
      fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Lifestyle.class.getName()));
      fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,GeekChic.class.getName()));
      fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Contests.class.getName()));

   this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter1(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
    mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    }
```

and class Dropdown extends Activity

```
tblHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                _____>>>>How to go 3rd Fragment... which code here?? <<<_____
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of the `ViewPager`?

Comment: yes... but which parameter i have to pass into intent?Its Intent(context, *Activity)? *--> what i have to pass here?please i dont understand what you want to say help.... Luksprog

Comment: The `ViewPager` has a `setCurrentItem` method to specify a certain `position` in the `ViewPager`. I don't know how you setup your activities so I can't say anything about the intent you're talking about.

Comment: yes now Understand ...Its my Mistake.. Thanks a lot....I have also TabWidget class at middle ... Its working now ...Thanks Luksprog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewPager has a setCurrentItem method to specify a certain position in the ViewPager.

```
mpager.setcurrentitem(int i);
```